# Extend parachain lease on local testnet

Tags: parachain, extrinsic, local

I have a local testnet running and it works until the first lease period is up. Once the first lease period finishes the chain stops producing blocks. I am looking for an easy way to submit some extrinsics to extend the lease period for a parachain -- or would I have to do something more complex in order to accomplish this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you could call [sudo_schedule_parathread_upgrade](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/common/src/paras_sudo_wrapper.rs#L94-L109) first to onboard your chain. Then call [force_lease](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/common/src/slots/mod.rs#L164-L181) to change the lease.